# Animating window on hover in MacOs swift

Tags: swift, macos, animation

I have to create A blank frameless window (with an icon inside it) in MacOS. Doing a trackpad gesture (you can choose any) should result in expansion with an animated-bounce, including a moving icon inside it. It should look like the attached video. The black item is the window; the yellow is an icon; and the white area is just the OS background.

`

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  HoverAnimation
//
//  Created by DML-Admin on 10/05/23.
//

import Cocoa
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?
    let options: NSTrackingArea.Options = [.activeInActiveApp, .mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved]
    let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 0.3

    
    @IBOutlet weak var iconImage: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var animationView: NSView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let customView = CustomView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(customView)
    }

    
    override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
  
        print("Mouse Entered")
        let newSize = NSSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        animateViewSize(to: newSize)
    
    }
    
    override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
 
        print("Mouse Exited")
    }
    
    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {

        print("Mouse Moved")
    }
    
    func animateViewSize(to newSize: NSSize) {
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
            context.duration = animationDuration
            self.animationView.animator().frame.size = newSize
        }, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}

class CustomView: NSView {
    var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?
    
    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        super.updateTrackingAreas()
        
        if let trackingArea = trackingArea {
            removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
        }
        
        let options: NSTrackingArea.Options = [.activeInActiveApp, .mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved]
        trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        addTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What is the question?